# How do I represent the data in a JSON format?

Tags: java, json

I have a very basic question here. I am trying to represent the below data in a JSON format.

```
haschanged=true
version=1
timestamp=1390561121310
DATACENTER=/pr/hello/plc
    TotalNumberOfServers:4
    primary:{0=1, 1=2, 2=1, 3=2, 4=1, 5=2, 6=1, 7=2, 8=1, 9=2, 10=1, 11=2, 12=1, 13=2}
    secondary:{0=0, 1=0, 2=0, 3=1, 4=0, 5=0, 6=0, 7=1, 8=0, 9=0, 10=0, 11=1, 12=0, 13=0}
    hosttomachine:{3=plcdbx1115.plc.domain.com, 2=plcdbx1114.plc.domain.com, 1=plcdbx1113.plc.domain.com, 4=plcdbx1116.plc.domain.com}
DATACENTER=/pr/hello/pty
    TotalNumberOfServers:2
    primary:{0=1, 1=2, 2=1, 3=2, 4=1, 5=2, 6=1, 7=2, 8=1, 9=2, 10=1, 11=2, 12=1, 13=2, 14=1}
    secondary:{0=0, 1=0, 2=0, 3=1, 4=0, 5=0, 6=0, 7=1, 8=0, 9=0, 10=0, 11=1, 12=0, 13=0, 14=0}
    hosttomachine:{1=ptydbx1145.pty.domain.com, 4=ptydbx1148.pty.domain.com}
```

I am not able to understand how do I represent the above data in a JSON format. This is what I have tried but not sure whether this is right?

```
{
    "haschanged": "true",
    "version": "1",
    "timestamp": "1390561121310",
    "/pr/hello/plc":
        {
        // not sure what should I do next?          
        },
    "/pr/hello/pty":
        {
        // not sure what should I do next?          
        }
}
```

Comment: You might want to represent the data centers as an array. `"DataCenters": [{ "name" : "/pr/hello/pty", ...}, { "name" : "/pr/hello/plc", ...}]`

Comment: Yeah I think, you are right.. Can you provide an example how I can do that? I am just confused..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use like this;

Use **"** for key value pairs

**Edit:** I have put only one item in **DATACENTER** key. You can do another by yourself

```
{
   "haschanged":true,
   "version":1,
   "timestamp":1390561121310,
   "DATACENTER":[
      {
         "name":"/pr/hello/plc",
         "TotalNumberOfServers":4,
         "primary":[
            {
               "0":"1"
            },
            {
               "1":"2"
            },
            {
               "2":"1"
            },
            {
               "3":"2"
            },
            {
               "4":"1"
            },
            {
               "5":"2"
            },
            {
               "6":"1"
            },
            {
               "7":"2"
            },
            {
               "8":"1"
            },
            {
               "9":"2"
            },
            {
               "10":"1"
            },
            {
               "11":"2"
            },
            {
               "12":"1"
            },
            {
               "13":"2"
            }
         ],
         "secondary":[
            {
               "0":"0"
            },
            {
               "1":"0"
            },
            {
               "2":"0"
            },
            {
               "3":"1"
            },
            {
               "4":"0"
            },
            {
               "5":"0"
            },
            {
               "6":"0"
            },
            {
               "7":"1"
            },
            {
               "8":"0"
            },
            {
               "9":"0"
            },
            {
               "10":"0"
            },
            {
               "11":"1"
            },
            {
               "12":"0"
            },
            {
               "13":"0"
            }
         ],
         "hosttomachine":[
            {
               "3":"plcdbx1115.plc.domain.com"
            },
            {
               "2":"plcdbx1114.plc.domain.com"
            },
            {
               "1":"plcdbx1113.plc.domain.com"
            },
            {
               "4":"plcdbx1116.plc.domain.com"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. I just tried validating this JSON. And it gives this exception - `Parse error on line 8:
...ary": {            0=1,            1=2
----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', '}'`. Any thoughts what is wrong?

Comment: Now it is valid, and I have conerted DATACENTER attr to array. Because there is multiple DATACENTER attribute

Answer (score 0):

Use a list for datacenters and you are good to go.

Here's how can can do it:

```
{
    "haschanged": "true",
    "version": "1",
    "timestamp": "1390561121310",
    "DATACENTER" = [
        { "name" : "/pr/hello/plc",
          "TotalNumberOfServers": 4,
          "primary": { 0=1, 1=2, 2=1, 3=2, 4=1, 5=2, 6=1, 7=2, 8=1, 9=2, 10=1, 11=2, 12=1, 13=2},
          "secondary": { 0=0, 1=0, 2=0, 3=1, 4=0, 5=0, 6=0, 7=1, 8=0, 9=0, 10=0, 11=1, 12=0, 13=0},
          "hosttomachine": { 3=plcdbx1115.plc.domain.com, 2=plcdbx1114.plc.domain.com, 1=plcdbx1113.plc.domain.com, 4=plcdbx1116.plc.domain.com}"

        },

        { "name": "/pr/hello/pty",
          "TotalNumberOfServers": 2,
          "primary": { 0=1, 1=2, 2=1, 3=2, 4=1, 5=2, 6=1, 7=2, 8=1, 9=2, 10=1, 11=2, 12=1, 13=2, 14=1},
          "secondary": { 0=0, 1=0, 2=0, 3=1, 4=0, 5=0, 6=0, 7=1, 8=0, 9=0, 10=0, 11=1, 12=0, 13=0, 14=0},
          "hosttomachine": { 1=ptydbx1145.pty.domain.com, 4=ptydbx1148.pty.domain.com}
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Your json is wrong. primary, secondary, hostmachine part must be array and the array values must be key value pair. http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ validation false

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing that out. I just found out that the primary, secondary and hostmachine should be array of key-value pairs. Please, refer to answer by @HüseyinBABAL .